# SPFX - React JS : How to handle an empty list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

SPFX-ReactJS newbie here. Wondering how I should handle an empty list.

I am trying to connect my web part to a list and simply display them on my web part and automatically update the page as items are added or deleted from the list. As long as I have at least one item in my list when I start the workbench it appears to be working. If I add an item to my list, I see the item on my web part.

Cool, but if I then delete the last item in my list - it still appears in my web part.

How can I make that go away? Also, when I first start on the workbench, if my list is empty and I add an item - it will not automatically update.

Here is what my `.tsx` file currently looks like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ReactWebPartDemo.module.scss';
import { IReactWebPartDemoProps } from './IReactWebPartDemoProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { IReactWebPartDemoState } from "./IReactWebPartDemoStat";
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";

import { IColor } from '../IColor';
import { ColorList, IColorListProps } from './ColorList';
import { colProperties } from '@uifabric/utilities';
import { SPList, SPListItem } from '@microsoft/sp-page-context';

export default class ReactWebPartDemo extends React.Component<IReactWebPartDemoProps, IReactWebPartDemoState> {


  constructor(props: IReactWebPartDemoProps){
    super(props);
    this.state = {colors:[]};

  }
  private getColorsFromSPList(): Promise<IColor[]>{
    return new Promise<IColor[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      const endpoint: string = `${this.props.currentSiteUrl}/_api/lists/getbytitle('Colors')/items?select=Title`
      this.props.spHttpClient.get(endpoint, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((jsonResponse: any) => {
        let spListItemColors: IColor[] = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < jsonResponse.value.length; index++){
          spListItemColors.push({
            id: jsonResponse.value[index].Id,
            title: jsonResponse.value[index].Title
          });

          resolve(spListItemColors);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void{
    this.getColorsFromSPList()
      .then((spListItemColors: IColor[]) => {
        this.setState({colors: spListItemColors});         
      })  
   }  

   public componentDidUpdate():void
   {
    this.getColorsFromSPList()
      .then((spListItemColors: IColor[]) => {
        this.setState({colors: spListItemColors});         
      })  

   }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactWebPartDemoProps> {         

    return (
        <div className={ styles.reactWebPartDemo }>
          <div className={ styles.container }>
            <div className={ styles.row }>
              <div className={ styles.column }>                                                      
                <ColorList colors={this.state.colors}/>           
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>   

    )        
  }

  /*
  private _removeColor = (colorToRemove: IColor): void => {
    const newColors = this.state.colors.filter(color => color != colorToRemove);
    this.setState({colors: newColors });    
  }
  */

}
```

I'm working on getting the SPFx debug feature working. In the meantime here is what my ColorList component looks like (ColorList.tsx)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {IColor} from '../IColor';
import styles from './ReactWebPartDemo.module.scss';


import { List } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/List';
import { DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { getItemStyles } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/ContextualMenu/ContextualMenu.classNames';

export type RemoveColorCallback = (color: IColor) => void;

export interface IColorListProps {
    colors: IColor[];  
}


export class ColorList extends React.Component<IColorListProps, {}>{

    public render(): React.ReactElement<IColorListProps>{


                return (           
                    <List items={ this.props.colors }           
                        onRenderCell={ this._onRenderListCell }/>       
                );

    }

    private _onRenderListCell = (color: IColor, index: number | undefined): JSX.Element => {
        return (                   
            <div className={styles.title}>
                { color.title }  
            </div>
        )         
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably throwing an error inside the ColorList component.  Can you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

An empty list means no colors in state, am I right? So just a small insert in your render method should work I guess:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactWebPartDemoProps> {         

    return (
        <div className={ styles.reactWebPartDemo }>
          <div className={ styles.container }>
            <div className={ styles.row }>
              <div className={ styles.column }>                                                      
                this.state.colors == null ? <span> No items available </span> : <ColorList colors={this.state.colors}/>           
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>   

    )        
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and I'm getting the same behavior....everything seems to work the way I want it to unless there is nothing for the webpart to show. I still have to do a manual refresh of the page if I delete/mark the last list item to not display.